# How to enter a new contribution?

Tags: contributions

How do I enter a new contribution for a donor in CiviCRM? I cannot find the tab to enter a new contribution for an already existing donor.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the link in the contributions menu for adding new contributions against a contact.

[image: Add New Contribution]

By clicking the link you will be redirected to add contribution page, where you will be able to find the contact from the select contact option.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find an extensive instruction in the manual https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-entry-of-contributions/ .

Answer (score 2):

For an already existing donor -> from the Donor's record -> hit the Contributions tab -> and then hit either the Record Contribution button (if you'd like to record a cash/cheque Contribution) OR the Submit Credit Card button (if you'd like to process/record a credit card Contribution):

[image]